# Getting an error with my model project and DAL specifically with my Text Template in C# .NET 4.5 and ObservableListSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I am using .NET 4.5/4.6 and C#.

I am trying to follow the following sites [Generic DAL](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/) and [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx) with my winforms application. I was able to implement link 2, however after implementing part of link 1 (specifically after moving my model Text Template, I have errors stating that `The type or namespace name 'ObservableListSource<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What namespace do I need to reference at the project level to fix this for my solution or what reference do I need to include with my text template in order for the entities to contain no errors?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this `ObservableListSource`](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/test/EntityFramework/FunctionalTests.Transitional/TestHelpers/ObservableListSource%60.cs)  the proper namespace would be `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: One question that comes up, why not just implement the EDMX file in its own project, rather than split it apart?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. the answer is at the beginning of [Databinding with winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx). Its a section of code that was overlooked several times and not a c# keyword.